# Make an http post request to send a JSON file in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, post, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I would like to send a `JSON file from my WP7 device to my local server`. On iOS I used the `ASIHttpRequest` library and what I did was :

```
//send json file , using ASIHttpClass
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.timeOutSeconds = TIME_OUT_SECONDS;
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

NSString *credentials= [self encodeCredentials];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Basic %@",credentials]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];        

[request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request startSynchronous];

if([request responseStatusCode]==200){
   return true;
} else {
     return false;
    }
```

How could I implement the same functionality in my WP7 application?

What i ve found till now and i think i am close :

```
//Making a POST request using WebClient.

Function()
{    
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();

  var URI = new Uri("http://your_uri_goes_here");

  wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic (here goes my credentials string which i have)";

  wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

 wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);

 wc_cart_session.UploadStringAsync(URI,"POST","Data_To_Be_sent");    

}
```

where :

```
void wc__UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{  
  try            
  {          
     MessageBox.Show(e.Result); 
//e.result fetches you the response against your POST request.
 }
  catch(Exception exc)         
  {             
     MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());            
  }
}
```

I suppose that the "Data_to_be_Sent" should be the jsonString in utf8 encoding?

### EDIT

---

I have noticed that the `"Data_To_Be_sent"` is a string. However this should be in UTF8 encoding right? So it should be a an array of bytes which are in UTF8 format. However i can only place a string there. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebClient` class has an [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property which the `UploadStringAsync` and `DownloadStringAsync` methods use. Set your encoding there.

```
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);   

wc.UploadStringAsync(URI,"POST","Data_To_Be_sent");
```

Comment: i also get an error that "wc_cart_session" does not exist in the current context . And what about the "Data to be Sent" . Seems like it should be a string. But what about if i need to send an array of bytes in UTF8 format?

Comment: Replace `wc_cart_session` with `wc` (I copy/pasted your code).

Comment: hm probably yes , but thats how it was on the tutorial , i thought it was a special var or smth.

Comment: I think you need to read up on C# a bit more to understand what's going on here. Read the `Encoding` link in my answer. It explains how the string is converted to a byte array for you.