# How to convert a string to UTF-8 string format in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, utf-8

I have a string in my WP7 application.

I need to send this string to my server in UTF-8 format.
How can i convert any string to UTF-8 format?

I have tried this so far :

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(jsonString);

string jsonStringUTF8 = Convert.ToString(encodedBytes);
```

where jsonString is the string i need in UTF8  format.

However when i try to print the new jsonStringUTF8 by doing :

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("JsonStringUTF8 is: {0}", jsonStringUTF8);
```

what i get is :

> JsonStringUTF8 is: System.Byte[]

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on how you send data to your server, send either `jsonString` or `encodedBytes`. You don't need `jsonStringUTF8`.

Comment: What i know is that the server accepts a jsonstring in utf8 encoding.. Is it already in that encoding? The equivalent iOS code that WORKS can be found here if you would like to take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088288/make-an-http-post-request-to-send-a-json-file-in-wp7  as you can see here , i use some encoding through the ASIHttpRequest library

Comment: Strings are in no encoding. They are strings. If you want to send a string to a server, it needs to be converted to bytes first. Converting to bytes requires the use of an encoding. This conversation can be done by yourself (`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`) or by the library you're using for sending stuff to the server. You haven't told us what library you're using. (Is it [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)?)

Comment: yes you can see what i am trying to do actually in the question i told you

Comment: @donparalias - If you are going to use `Convert.ToString(byte[]) you have to provide the encoding you used.  The results your getting is to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert the `byte` array to a string by using `Convert.ToString`. You need to decode it because it's an UTF8-encoded byte array.

```
string jsonStringUTF8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedBytes, 0,encodedBytes.Length)
```

Comment: I get this error : 'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @donparalias - I've changed the answer to the overloaded version (since it's Silverlight).

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much sir. If possible would you like to comment on what Mr. dtb is saying on the above comments? Cause i am a bit confused now. What i am trying to do is wrong as he says or correct?

Comment: No, what you're doing it fine (and is actually what dtb is saying). You're encoding the byte array using an UTF8 encoder (you can make that one line by using the method he mentioned `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);`. This returns a byte array containing the UTF8 encoded string. You can then pass this byte array to your clients (or wherever) and your client can decode the string by the method in my answer. His first comment is saying that you can either send the string or the byte array but don't send both (no point).

Comment: @donparalias - All `dtb` is saying is that you should only send the byte[] then decode and covert the byte[] when its recieved.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong. What i thought in the beginning was that the original jsonString that i create was not in UTF8 format and that the jsonStringUTF8 is in UTF8 format and thats the one i should send. But from what i understand now UTF8 format is not a string! is an array of bytes! So jsonString = JsonStringUTF8 as these are the (original) and the (encoded -> decoded) strings which are absolutely the same. The UTF8 format that should be send is the var encodedBytes. Am i right?

Comment: Also if possible could you take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088288/make-an-http-post-request-to-send-a-json-file-in-wp7

Comment: @donparalias -  I don't know what the original `jsonString` format was as it depends where you got it from. .NET strings use UTF16 by default. It's a good idea to send as bytes because other systems, which may not read the string with a UTF16/UTF8 decoder by default, can simply decode it with its own UTF-8 decoder. So yes, you can send the `encodedBytes` array which contains the UTF8 encoded string. Your client will receive this byte array and you can call the `GetString` method on the UTF8 decoder to turn it back into a string with the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in the CLR are, per the spec, UTF-16 encoded Unicode characters. You literally cannot create a UTF-8 **string**, *per se*. A UTF-8 encoded `byte[]` can turn it back into a [UTF-16] string with code like this:

```
byte[]  rawUtf8EncodedData = ReadSomeUtf8EncodedBytes() ;
string  decodedString      = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rawUtf8EncodedData ) ;
```

You can also explicitly create a UTF8 `Decoder` and use that to do the conversion, or (a final technique) might be to use `System.IO` facilities:

```
string value ;

byte[]  rawUtf8EncodedData = ReadSomeUtf8EncodedBytes() ;
using ( MemoryStream utf8Stream = new MemoryStream( rawUtf8EncodedData ) )
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( utf8Stream , Encoding.UTF8 ) )
{
  value = reader.ReadToEnd() ;
}
```

It should be noted that should your source data carry a BOM, it will be present in the converted string, though invisible and inaccessible to you. Got bit by that with an XML reader barfing on the BOM where there should not have been one.

Here's Jon Skeet's article on strings, http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx, and his article on Unicode and Encodings at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx .